# Flutter gridview odds - last cell to take complete width of row

Tags: flutter, dart

Odds `Grid View`. Is there a way to horizontally center the 7th item to take the complete length of a row? I am trying to achieve the following image using `GridView`. Thank you for your help.

[image: GridView]

Comment: Please put the code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it using GridView but you can do it using [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) library

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int count = 7;
    return Scaffold(
        body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: new Center(
            child: new CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: new Text('$index'),
            ),
          )),
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
        if (count % 2 != 0 && count - 1 == index) {
          return new StaggeredTile.count(4, 1);
        }
        return new StaggeredTile.count(2, 1);
      },
      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    ));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi can you please let me know how to increase the height of these tiles @Sanjay Sharma

Comment: Did you try setting the height and the width of a widget?

Comment: yes but I want to set return new StaggeredTile.count(4, 1); dynamic like dynamic count for each cell kinda Facebook like grid

Comment: do you have any idea? @Sanjay Sharma

Comment: You can have a method dynamically creating the widgets of different size.

Comment: any code snipet please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212919/hello-guys-want-to-create-a-feed-in-flutter-similar-to-facebook-style-images

Comment: if its possible you can answer the above question